# PHP filesize error stat failed

Tags: php, filesize, getfiles

I'm using this simple code to catch the file size:

```
$photoSIZE = filesize($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$attachSIZE = filesize($_FILES['attach']['name']);
```

i receive the error:

```
filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed
```

i uploaded a 21mb file

what should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call filesize(), you can get the size of uploaded files as follows:

```
$photoSIZE = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
$attachSIZE = $_FILES['attach']['size'];
```

Alternatively, you can use filesize() as you did but you have to do it on the tmp_name var which holds the path of the uploaded file, as follows:

```
$photoSIZE = filesize( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] );
$attachSIZE = filesize( $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'] );
```

Take a look at the [PHP file upload documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more info on these variables.